# Hide an empty list filter in Einstein analytics dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics, dashboard, filters, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I'd like to know if it is possible to hide a list filter in a Einstein Analytics Dashboard if this filter has no available values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding widgets is not possible at the moment at all.

The only thing I can imagine is using a link widget. Depending on whether your filter is empty or not you bind a different Page to the widget. But that does not allow you to dynamically show/hide the filter unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that's what I was thinking but wanted to be sure